# Call GetStoredProcCommand with variable number of arguments in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, arguments, enterprise-library, system.data

In my code I am repeating code blocks like this all the time:

```
var returnData = MyDb.ExecuteDataSet(
    MyDb.GetStoredProcCommand("MyTable_Insert", columnOne, columnTwo, columnThree),
    transaction
);

var returnId = (int)returnData.Tables[0].Rows[0]["INSERTED_ID"];
```

This seems to me to be a fairly large block of code to be repeating so many times, but I can't work out how to generalise it into a method because the number of arguments is different to each stored procedure.

The obvious solution (to me) is to pass my parameters through to the function in an array and then expand them to call `GetStoredProcCommand`, but I can't find a way to do this:

```
private int CallStoredProcedure(string procName, List<dynamic> parameterValues) {
    ..
    MyDb.GetStoredProcCommand(procName, expand parameterValues);
    // ERROR: Obviously "expand" doesn't exist
    ..
}
```

I could use the longer-winded way passing parameters using `AddInParameter`, but then I would need to pass type information along with the parameter values:

```
private int CallStoredProcedure(string procName, IDictionary<DbType, IDictionary<string, string>> paramsKeyValuesByType) {
    ..
    MyDb.AddInParameter(myProcCommand, param.Value.Key, param.Key, param.Value.Value);
    ..
}
```

But then I'd have to construct the `IDictionary` object before calling the method which would be even more long-winded than how I was originally calling the procedure.

Can anyone think of an elegant solution to this?

Comment: If you're using variable arguments in `MyDb.GetStoredProcCommand`, why wouldn't you just use variable arguments as well in `CallStoredProcedure`?  Variable arguments are stored in an array  which can be directly passed instead of an expanded list.

Comment: Are you sure you mean `dynamic` and not `object`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `params` keyword:

```
private int CallStoredProcedure(string procName, params object[] parameterValues) {
    ..
    MyDb.GetStoredProcCommand(procName, parameterValues);
    ..
}
```

Comment: I don't think this helps me because how do I then pass those variable parameters through to `GetStoredProcCommand` - wouldn't that have to be defined using the `params` keyword? I couldn't get it to work that way. I'm happy to be corrected.

Comment: @RobinWinslow: You don't have to do anything. Check the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb748722(v=pandp.31).aspx). As you can see, `GetStoredProcCommand` uses `params` too, so it should just work. Why do you think it won't work? Did you try it? What error did you get?

Comment: Good point. This whole `params` thing confused me a little, but now I understand it.